# AWS DataPipeline via Cloudformation throws error 'type is not defined in fields'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-data-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy the [Export DynamoDB Table to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exportddbtos3.html) template via Cloudformation but getting a `type is not defined in fields` error from Cloudformation. I have a `Key` with the value of `type` for all of my `PipelineObjects` with the exception of the `Default` ParameterObject so I'm not sure what the error is referring to. Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be going on here? Thanks!

```
DataPipeline:
Type: AWS::DataPipeline::Pipeline
Properties:
  Name: ddb-export
  ParameterObjects:
    - Attributes:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: String
        - Key: description
          StringValue: Region of the DynamoDB table
        - Key: default
          StringValue: us-west-2
      Id: myDDBRegion
    - Attributes:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: String
        - Key: description
          StringValue: Source DynamoDB table name
      Id: myDDBTableName
    - Attributes:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: Double
        - Key: description
          StringValue: DynamoDB read throughput ratio
        - Key: default
          StringValue: "0.25"
      Id: myDDBReadThroughputRatio
    - Attributes:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: AWS::S3::ObjectKey
        - Key: description
          StringValue: Output S3 folder
      Id: myOutputS3Loc
  Activate: false
  PipelineObjects:
    - Fields:
        - Key: scheduleType
          StringValue: ondemand
        - Key: failureAndRerunMode
          StringValue: CASCADE
        - Key: role
          StringValue: datapipeline-ddb-export
        - Key: resourceRole
          StringValue: datapipeline-ddb-export-resource
      Id: Default
      Name: Default
    - Fields:
        - Key: tableName
          RefValue: "#{myDDBTableName}"
        - Key: type
          StringValue: DynamoDBDataNode
        - Key: readThroughputPercent
          RefValue: "#{myDDBReadThroughputRatio}"
      Id: DDBSourceTable
      Name: DDBSourceTable
    - Fields:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: S3DataNode
        - Key: directoryPath
          StringValue: "#{myOutputS3Loc}/#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')}"
      Id: S3BackupLocation
      Name: S3BackupLocation
    - Fields:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: EmrCluster
        - Key: releaseLabel
          StringValue: emr-5.23.0
        - Key: masterInstanceType
          StringValue: m3.xlarge
        - Key: coreInstanceType
          StringValue: m3.xlarge
        - Key: coreInstanceCount
          StringValue: "1"
        - Key: region
          StringValue: "#{myDDBRegion}"
      Id: EmrClusterForBackup
      Name: EmrClusterForBackup
    - Fields:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: EmrActivity
        - Key: input
          RefValue: DDBSourceTable
        - Key: output
          RefValue: S3BackupLocation
        - Key: runsOn
          RefValue: EmrClusterForBackup
        - Key: resizeClusterBeforeRunning
          StringValue: "true"
        - Key: maximumRetries
          StringValue: "2"
        - Key: step
          StringValue: s3://dynamodb-dpl-#{myDDBRegion}/emr-ddb-storage-handler/4.11.0/emr-dynamodb-tools-4.11.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar,org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBExport,#{output.directoryPath},#{input.tableName},#{input.readThroughputPercent}
      Id: TableBackupActivity
      Name: TableBackupActivity
Metadata:
  aws:cdk:path: ddb-export-CELL-dev/DataPipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `Default` pipelineObject needs a `type` of `Default`